# No validations errors to display in symfony 1.4 form

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

I have a problem with all my forms in symfony 1.4. They work with good datas, my new objects are created ... But when i give bad datas, my forms do nothing as expected but have no errors.

My code in my action :

```
$this->form = new EtablissementForm();

$this->form->bind(
  $request->getParameter($this->form->getName()),
  $request->getFiles($this->form->getName())
);
```

Edit :

Solved. I guess i need some sleep. This was really a dumb mistake. I was sure i had removed a new E...Form(); In my view for my action, actually i did it ... in another file.

So my $form was overwritten by an empty form. So the problem is solved.

```
if ($this->form->isValid())
{
  //some things and a redirect
}
```

In a nutshell, my form works with good datas. But i don't have any errors to display when i'm giving bad datas. And my form don't add something in my database. Validations works cause it raise exception in bind, but i just get an empty form to display.

Comment: did you try to see what's in $form->hasErrors() and $form->getErrors()? Maybe you just forgot to display them in the template?

Comment: HasErrors and get errors have no errors. And i have my renderError() for all my widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view needs to have proper scope to $form. Your code above may be incomplete. In the action you show above, if the action ends, and you go to your view, and your view has the following, your validation errors should appear inline with your form.

```
  <?php echo $form ?>
```

Comment: I am not sure i get your point. My form is inside a partial, which gets $form from the view which get it from the action. The form work properly with good datas(according to my validators), but when my form is invalid, i get an empty form. So it have no errors, nor values.  I get an empty form whereas my $form in my view is the same object form who got the binding. So i don't really understand where the problem is. Cause it works with good datas, my validators work when i'm giving bad datas, but the errors disapear between my $form->bind and my view.